# Templated functions with distinct definitions based on type

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

Assume we have different classes (structs) with different member types and counts. For the sake of the example, they are 2D and 3D vectors.

```
struct i2 { 
    int a, b; 
    i(int a, int b): a(a), b(b) {}
};

struct f2 { 
    float a, b;
    f(float a, float b): a(a), b(b) {}
};

struct i3 { 
    int a, b, c; 
    i(int a, int b): a(a), b(b), c(c) {}
};

struct f3 { 
    float a, b, c;
    f(float a, float b): a(a), b(b), c(c) {}
};
```

I would like to implement some related functions in a templated way. Say an addition operator outside the classes, like

```
template<class Type> Type operator+(const Type& P, const& Type Q)
  { return Type(P.a + Q.b, P.a + P.b); }
```

Obviously, this won't work with the 3D variants, which would require

```
template<class Type> Type operator+(const Type& P, const Type& Q)
  { return Type(P.a + Q.a, P.b + P.b, P.c + Q.c); }
```

Is there a nice way to achieve this without numerous explicit specializations ? And if this uses advanced C++ features, what is the minimum version that will support it ?

In other words, is there a compile-time mechanism to conditionally instantiate the templates based on the argument types ?

Note that I prefer the initial classes to remain non-templated because this would introduce other issues in my design.

Comment: Who said anything about specializations? Just add a `+` operator overload to each class. Can't get any simpler than that. Or, use a template to define each 3D vector, with a `+` operator, to do this just once.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: my model has more classes and more operators and more functions to overload, though with much code in common. This is why I want to use templates.

Comment: Like I said, if all the 3D vectors differ only in their values' type, use a template to define all 3D vector, complete with a `+` overload.

Comment: The 2D and 3D templated operator+ definitions will collide, as they share the same  prototype.

Comment: Use SFINAE.  But I agree that `i2`, etc. should really be template specializations.  This will make everything a lot easier.

Comment: @L.F.: I am afraid that SFINAE can avoid the 3D template to be used on a 2D vector (because the `c` component will be missing), but not the other way.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You can write a trait and apply `!` on it.

Comment: Using SFINAE to have something that works on a 2D vector, but not the 3D vector, should be fairly easy. If you make a standalone question just for that, someone should be able to whip up an answer.

Comment: @L.F.: thank you, I'll be looking at traits.

Answer (score 1):

You might use SFINAE once you have your traits.

traits can be done in any version of C++, even if it would be easier with more recent version.

Depending how you want to define your traits, you might use something like

```
template <typename T>
using is_2d_vector = std::disjunction_t<std::is_same<T, i2>, std::is_same<T, f2>>;

template <typename T>
using is_3d_vector = std::disjunction_t<std::is_same<T, i3>, std::is_same<T, f3>>;

// possible alternatives include detection of T::a, T::b, T::c

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<is_2d_vector<T>, int> = 0>
T operator+(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{ return T(lhs.a + rhs.a, lhs.b + rhs.b); }

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<is_3d_vector<T>, int> = 0>
T operator+(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{ return T(lhs.a + rhs.a, lhs.b + rhs.b, lhs.c + rhs.c); }
```

But having template class initially seems simpler:

```
template <typename T>
struct T2 { 
    T a, b;
    T2(T a, T b): a(a), b(b) {}

    friend operator +(const T2& lhs, const T2& rhs)
    { return T(lhs.a + rhs.a, lhs.b + rhs.b); }
};

template <typename T>
struct T3 { 
    T a, b, c; 
    T3(T a, T b, T c): a(a), b(b), c(c) {}

    friend operator +(const T2& lhs, const T2& rhs)
    { return T(lhs.a + rhs.a, lhs.b + rhs.b, lhs.c + rhs.c); }
};

using i2 = T2<int>;
using i3 = T3<int>;
using f2 = T2<float>;
using f3 = T3<float>;
```

Comment: "Any version of C++" seems a little exaggerated. If I am right, traits were introduced with C++11, which precludes the use of Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 that I need to support. (But for the sake of elegance I could make the sacrifice.)

Comment: `<type_traits>` is indeed from C++11, but most traits by themselves can be implemented prior C++11. `is_same` and even some detections can be implemented prior C++11. I think boost should provide some. (my example indeed use latest provided syntax/traits).

Comment: @YvesDaoust `is_same` can be easily implemented. `disjunction` can be replaced by `::value || ::value`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it I think is to use compile time (static) reflection. There are quite a few of articles online, here are two of them,  https://medium.com/@vesko.karaganev/compile-time-reflection-in-c-17-55c14ee8106b
and 
https://Frly.sexy/post/basic-reflection-in-pure-cpp17

But I am not sure this is the best way to solve your problem because a better answer would need more concrete details.